# Visual Studio 2019 / Code Review tool to count the number of lines that has been modified

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

We currently use Visual Studio 2019+TFS 2018 with DevArt ReviewAssistant for peer review. I would like to know how many lines of code have been changed in order too keep our review small, but neither of VS or ReviewAssistant seems to be able to do this.

Do you know a tool that would work with VS2019/TFS2018 that can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Code Churn Report** to achieve this.

> You can report on the software quality by using the Code Churn and Run
>   Coverage perspectives from the SQL Server Analysis Services cube for
>   Team Foundation Server. By using these perspectives, you can view just
>   the measures, dimensions, and attributes that are associated with the
>   changes in lines of codes and the extent to which code is covered in
>   builds and test runs.

[image]

You should be able to create the report based on Team project and specific date.(Build/Release date) to view the Lines of code Added, Deleted and Modified.

Detail tutorials for your reference:

- [Analyze and report on code churn and coverage using the code churn
  and run coverage perspectives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/perspective-code-analyze-report-code-churn-coverage?view=azure-devops-2019)
- [Code Churn tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/table-reference-code-churn?view=tfs-2018)
- [Getting Started with the TFS Data Warehouse](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html)

Comment: yeah but I don't want report on code change in the source control, I want to know how many lines of code in pending changes before sending to code review prior to checkin-in

Comment: @Jonathan For pending changes, we do not have any build-in tool to track this. You may have to compare your code file with history version through some 3rd-party extension. Sorry for any inconvenience.